# Getting Rasterio transform/affine from lat and long array

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I have lat, long, and data arrays

```py
data = np.array [[1,3],[2,3],[3,4]]

lat = np.array [[44,43],[46,44],[43,45]]

long = np.array [[33,32],[31,33],[36,33]]
```

The coordinates here are random but my question is how to get the rasterio transform from such objects, my original image is a slanted rectangle so the `rasterio.transform.from_bounds(west, south, east, north, width, height)` didn't work out.

My final goal is to write the data array as a GeoTIFF.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`rasterio.transform.from_gcps`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html#rasterio.transform.from_gcps):

1. Get the upper-left, upper-right, lower-left & lower-right corner
   coordinates from your arrays in lon, lat / x, y order.
2. Create GCPs for each corner
3. Pass a list of GCPs to the `from_gcps` function

In the example below I've used an actual dataset that I know the coordinates of.

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.transform import from_gcps
from rasterio.control import GroundControlPoint as GCP

ul = (10.0000000, 30.0000000)  # in lon, lat / x, y order
ll = (80.7106781, -40.7106781)
ur = (80.7110000, 100.711)
lr = (151.4213562, 30.0000000)
cols, rows = 20, 20

gcps = [
    GCP(0, 0, *ul),
    GCP(0, cols, *ur),
    GCP(rows, 0, *ll),
    GCP(rows, cols, *lr)
]

transform = from_gcps(gcps)

# Check derived transform angainst dataset transform
with rio.open('byte_rotated.tif') as tif:
    print(tif.transform)
    print(transform)
```

Output:

```
| 3.54, 3.54, 10.00|
| 3.54,-3.54, 30.00|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|

| 3.54, 3.54, 10.00|
| 3.54,-3.54, 30.00|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
```

[image]

However your arrays of coordinates likely represent the centre of each pixel, so your GCPs should look like:

```
gcps = [
    GCP(0.5, 0.5, *ul),  # Centre of top-left pixel
    GCP(0.5, cols, *ur),
    GCP(rows-0.5, 0.5, *ll),
    GCP(rows-0.5, cols-0.5, *lr)
]
```